# Typescript complaining about TextArea element for having rows prop?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have a reusable input textarea component as shown below:

```
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';
import classes from './Input.module.css';
interface InputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement> {
    errorMessage?: string;
}
const TextArea = ({ errorMessage, ...rest }: InputProps) => (
    <div
        className={classes.InputBox}
        error-message={errorMessage ?? 'Invalid Input Provided'}
    >
        <textarea {...rest} />
    </div>
);
export default TextArea;
```

However when I use this:

```
<TextArea
                                    placeholder="Message"
                                    rows={4}
                                    value={message}
                                    onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                                />
```

TypeScript complains:

```
Type '{ placeholder: string; rows: number; value: string; onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps'.
  Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps'.
```

Can someone help me understand which type should I use to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputHTMLAttributes` is for `input` elements, not `textarea` elements. For `textarea` elements, use `TextareaHTMLAttributes`:

```typescript
interface InputProps extends TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement> {
    errorMessage?: string;
}
```

It has `rows`.